# Linkable revisions

Tags: feature-request, revision-history

At certain times I'd like to link to a specific revision of a post.

It's possible, but cumbersome:

- inspect source code of the revisions page
- pick the ID (`id="rev{guid}"`) of the revision in question
- build an URL `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/{id}/revisions#rev{guid}`

All the bits are there, it would be trivial to expose the revision GUID as a clickable link.

Many websites (most prominently documentation) provide little `#`-signs next to headings or other sections of interest as an convenient way to copy a link. I could imagine the same feature for the review list, making it much easier to talk about a certain revision.

I am aware of revision links like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/333807/2.

Currently they do not expose the same functionality as the full revision list. There is no way to switch between the rendering modes `inline` `side-by-side` and `side-by-side markdown` in this view, but being able to see a revision *in context* makes all the difference.

Comment: So you want to see the same view as you have in the revision history, but for only for a specific revision?  I'd strongly advise you add that to your question here because the feature as you described it already exists.

Comment: Added. Basically, I'd like to have hash links into the revision list. Whether they are by GUID or simply by revision number makes no difference. GUID is what works now. It's what could be exposed as a clickable `#` with minimal effort.

Comment: Links like those are only really useful if you can guarantee that ID will *always* be on that page in the future, which is not true with the revision history. They're paginated, and we only display 25 revisions per page. After that, revisions start falling onto another page and the previous link will no longer take you to it. You just end up at the top of whatever page was linked. Doing this properly would require additional redirect work that looks up a revision ID and determines the post and page, which might be more effort than being able to link to a revision inline is worth.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the underlying mechanics.